# How to install amdgpu-pro 18.50

Tags: drivers, system-installation, additional-drivers, amdgpu-pro

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 for mining purposes. So I need amdgpu-pro OpenCL driver.

First problem is that auto-login does not works after a fresh install. Minimal+third party option gets to login screen, but when I press user it "thinks" for a little and returns back to login screen. So I have to press a "gear" icon every time and select "Ubuntu wayland" everytime. This is unsuitable for unattended/remote operation. I hope this is easily solved.

But the main problem is when I downloaded, unpacked and run `amdgpu-pro-install` it installed but boot hangs on message "Started User Manager for UID 120".

Such a simple sequence is so buggy nowadays: "ubuntu-driver-miner-go..." Who is responsive and What to do?

PS. "install specialied mining distro" advice would be ignored, or I would ask advisor to pay for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For automatic login, unlock user account, turn it OFF and ON again. Restart to see if it restores normal behavior. After Kernel 4.18, amdgpu is included and there is no need to install it. Unzip 18.50 and click on _all.deb file to install it (inside the unzip folder).

Have you tried an higher Kernel, stable is 4.20.10 or mainline 5.0-rc7?

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

Comment: amdgpu is included, but not the opencl part, which is exactly what i need. `apt install clinfo` reports 0 platforms, that is useless for mining. When I install amdgpu nothing changes, but when I install amdgpu-pro system hangs at a boot screen. Boot hangs on message "Started User Manager for UID 120" and mouse does not appears.

Comment: I found it rather simplier to build kernel from scratch and a busybox, and manually unpack opencl libraries - that worked and is way more easier (than complicated ubuntu boot system, totally unknown to new user). I initially thought that linux distro would be much easier that building your own linux, but it is not so.